# Update changes in local sql server db to Sql Azure db immediately?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, database-schema

So far, when I make any changes to my local Db, to make those changes to sql azure db, I need to manually write script and run it on sql azure db. Is there any solution that help my sql azure db get updated quicker? Like right after I check in my code to source control, my sql azure db will be updated automatically? I do have one Db project in my solution. I heard about Redgate that might have some products that can solve my problem but I'm not sure. Any suggestion?

Ps: If this question is not appropriate to ask here, please warn me so I can delete it.

Edit: There is another way I normally use is to make a schema compare between db project and sql azure db and then update. This way I dont need to write script manually but I still need to do multiple steps to get db in azure updated.

Comment: Aren't you just looking for a Continuous Integration build, where the last step of the build is to run whatever is needed to deploy the database?

Comment: To be honest, I dont know what it is. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.sqlshack.com/continuous-integration-sql-server-data-tools-team-foundation-server/

Comment: You may want to use SQL Server Transactional Replication between your SQL Server instance on premise and AzureDB. We are currently enabling this capacity, the feature is in public preview. I have recorded a video for Microsoft Ignite that explains in details how it works. You will find this video here: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Data-Exposed/Azure-SQL-DB-Transactional-Replication.

Comment: Yeah, using Sql server transactional replication sounds promising but unfortunately it's not available for everyone yet...I'm looking to using it soon. Thanks!